# Passing $ in jQuery function. What's the use of $ sign?

Tags: jquery

As the Title says, kindly someone explain the use of $ sign in functoin.
I am using this code to smooth scroll to ID in WordPress.

When i remove $ sign, code does not work. I have to pass $ in function.
kindly refer to image.

Note: This code works without passing $ in function when using in HTML website but does not work in WordPress. Well, that nothing to worry but if some one could explain?

Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.scroll').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: No screenshots of code please. Just copy/paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is the name of a variable. It is equivalant to `jQuery` variable. Assume this code:

```
var $ = "my $ variable";
alert ($);
```

no magic about it, just a name.

Comment: Alright you mean $ refers to jQuery as a priority?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "priority", but the ` $ ` can be considered as _beeing_ jQuery.

Comment: I read some where that it's use for telling jquery that use give first priority to the code that has $ sign. Can you please elaborate a little about why we use $ sign?

Comment: There is no "priority" in use of variables. In order to learn more, refer to the other answers linked here or the jQuery docs.